# What is the cidr range for GCP VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

What is the maximum and minimum CIDR block size allowed while creating a VPC and its subnets in Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a VPC network with a subnet that has 10.0.0.0/8 which works just fine. While the smallest possible subnet is a /29

Answer (score 2):

By default, VPC networks do not have any IP address ranges associated with them. When you create a subnet, you must define a primary IP address range. You can optionally define one or more secondary ranges:

So, the answer to the question is that CIDR range mask length must not be greater than 29, which means that the minimum allowed is **/29**, while the maximum is **/9**.

**Example:**

```
Private Address Ranges for class A, B and C networks

Class   Private IP   Address Range    Subnet Mask

A      10.0.0.0      10.255.255.255   255.0.0.0    | 24-bit block
B      172.16.0.0    172.31.255.255   255.240.0.0  | 20-bit block
C      192.168.0.0   192.168.255.255  255.255.0.0  | 16-bit block
```

Comment: the maximum is /8 not /9!

Answer (score 0):

each vpc is a closed environment, so you can define a valid IPv4 range, I never had to define a network bigger than a /8, but I don't see why .

For the subnets I suggest a quick look at this part of the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#manually_created_subnet_ip_ranges